# elasticsearch kibana.yml file not found

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, kibana

In ubuntu elasticsearch `kibana.yml` file not found at location `/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml` which is usually the default path for `kibana.yml` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Older 4.x versions used the path `/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml` but that has been changed in 5.x to `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml` (which is consistent with Elasticsearch also).

So look for `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml`.

Comment: when I use Sudo nano /etc/kibana/kibana.yml I get an access denied message.